# impl Add<&MyType> for MyType はアンチパターン？

Tags: rust

[num](https://crates.io/crates/num) を使用していて、`BigRational` などは `Copy` を実装していないため、

```rust
let a: &BigRational;
let b: BigRational;
// ...
let c = a + b;
```

のようなことが出来ないことに気づきました。
`clone` がヘビーな可能性があるため `Copy` を実装していない、と言うのはわかるのですが、いちいち

```rust
let c = a + &b;
let d = &(a + a) + a
```

とするのは数式が複雑だと面倒です。

タイトルにあるように

```rust
impl Add<&BigRational> for BigRational
impl Add<BigRational> for &BigRational
```

を実装していれば自然に記述できるし、num の型がどうかはわかりませんがコピーを減らせる可能性もあります。
にもかかわらず num で実装されていないのは何か理由があるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use num::*;
fn test(a: &BigRational, b: BigRational) {
    let _c = a + b;
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=abad30b3a3c21ea293716ff4a3b6211a

これは問題なくコンパイルでき、また num 0.2.1 のリファレンスにも `impl<'a, T> Add<&'a Ratio<T>> for Ratio<T>`は存在しているように見えます。
https://docs.rs/num/0.2.1/num/rational/struct.Ratio.html#implementations

上記の通り多くのcrateで `impl Add<&MyType> for MyType` は実装されており特にアンチパターンという事は無いと思います。例えばN次元配列 `ndarray::ArrayBase` なども実装しています：
https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.0/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#implementations

Comment: 以前できなかったと思ったのですが、今試したところ出来ました。確認不十分だったようです。積極的に自作クラスでも4種実装していくことにします。